# auto-fit Grid Columns in UWP XAML

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm using GridView to create a grid of items, and im trying to make the columns fill to expand the remaining space. Similar to how `auto-fit` behaves in CSS. [See example.](https://codepen.io/joshhunt/pen/qBOdYjj).

Here I've set the MaxWidth of the GridView's children to 350px, and then when the window is not an even multiple of 350px + padding, I would like each column to expand to fill the remaining space.

[image]

Is this possible with UWP/XAML?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve the auto-fit effect, you can try to use [UniformGrid Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/uniformgrid) from Windows Community Toolkit. It is a responsive layout control which arranges items in a evenly-spaced set of rows or columns to fill the total available display space. First, you need to add **Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls** nuget package and then use it as GridView's **ItemsPanel**. For example:

.xaml:

```
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"

<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <controls:UniformGrid Columns="3" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: Hmm, I would like the number of columns to be dynamic based on the window size. Basically, I would like each cell's width to be something like `windowWidth / Floor( windowWidth / minCellWidth )`.

I'm starting to think a custom Panel might be the best bet. Is it possible/feasable to override this portion of GridView's behaviour?

Comment: If you want the number of columns to be dynamic, you can try to use [AdaptiveGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/adaptivegridview) to replace GridView without using a custom Panel.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a go. It looks promsing!